# WLActionReceiver not working on MobileFirst 8

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

i'm implementing the WLActionReceiver protocol in our Cordova-based MobileFirst 8 application.

I'm trying to send actions from Javascript to Native (Objective c) but actions are not received or the onActionReceived method is not called.

I implemented this code into the wlInitDidCompleteSuccessfully method to setup the ActionReceiver.

```
[[WL sharedInstance] addActionReceiver:[[ActionReceiver alloc] init]];
```

And this is the ActionReceiver code:

ActionReceiver.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid/WLActionReceiver.h>

@interface ActionReceiver : NSObject<WLActionReceiver>
@end
```

ActionReceiver.m

```
#import "ActionReceiver.h"

@implementation ActionReceiver

- (void)onActionReceived:(NSString *)action withData:(NSDictionary *)data {
    NSLog(@"onActionReceived");
}
```

I'm using this code to send action from Javascript:

```
var data = {someproperty:1234};
WL.App.sendActionToNative("DeviceID", data);
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: The code snippets seem OK, but it's hard to tell. Can you supply a demo app with your implementation of the API where it is failing? We can then investigate it further.

Comment: I just removed the ios application and re-created it using cordova cli and now it works... Thank you

Comment: Great. If you could please remove this question...

Comment: please see above.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been a setup issue, as performing the following actions resolved the issue:

`cordova platform remove ios`
`cordova platform add ios`